# Error-first callbacks and event-emitters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I implemented a module that exports an event-emitter.

My event emitter basically looks like this:

```
const EE = require('events');
const util = require('util');

function MyEventEmitter(){

   EE.call(this);


}

util.inherits(MyEventEmitter,EE);


MyEventEmitter.prototype.foo = function(data){

     this.emit('done-with-foo', {});

});

MyEventEmitter.prototype.bar = function(data){

     this.emit('done-with-bar', null, {});

});
```

what confuses me about event emitters in Node, is that we are supposed to use error first callbacks. But if we use my event emitter:

```
const ee = new MyEventEmitter();

ee.on('done-with-foo', function(err, data1,data2,data3,etc){

    if(err){
    //handle err
   }

});

ee.on('done-with-bar', function(err, data1,data2,data3,etc){

   if(err){
    //handle err
   }

});

  ee.foo();
  ee.bar();
```

in one case there is an error-first callback, but in the other, it is not error-first.

Which is the correct way to conform to the Node.js standard? Perhaps the correct way is to only use an error-first callback with an 'error' event?
Otherwise there is basically a guarantee that there is no error being passed?

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question, it depends on you. If there will never be an error to pass, and you always pass `null`, there's no need for an error argument. On the other hand, for consistency many people, myself included, still like to leave the error argument in there, simply because the callback to the `on()` handler will always look the same, and you never have to wonder what order the arguments are in.. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) are quite clear as well -> *"..best practice ... should always register listeners for the 'error'"*.

Comment: Your API, your rules. If you want an independent `error` or `bar-error` event or if you just want to enforce the first argument in the callback as an error, both seem fine to me.  Here is a [styleguide](https://github.com/RisingStack/node-style-guide#callbacks) that says to always check for errors in callbacks. I think of an `error` event as never sleeping, and it can fire at any time, which seems like a different use case, whereas an error callback is coupled with the associated action.